# Opposite of mainstream

Tags: single-word-requests

How do you define someone that does (not on purpose) quite the opposite of the general trend?

For example:

> My week schedule is quite packed with events except Friday evening, while it's usually the opposite we hear about.

I thought of *unconventional* and *peripheral*, which I got are antonyms for mainstream, but I am wondering if there is a better adjective for my situation.

Comment: *Unconventional* would imply intention. They might be *odd* or *in the minority*

Comment: Don't forget to add an example sentence in which you might like to use this word, or your question might be at risk of closure :)

Comment: abnormal
    eccentric
    exceptional
    extraordinary
    infrequent
    irregular
    rare
    secondary
    uncommon
    unusual
    heterodox

Comment: Not wanting to just add another synonym, consider **'offbeat': not conforming to the usual pattern/trend**. It is a slang as well. So your 'week schedule is quite/pretty/slightly offbeat.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps ***unorthodox*** will work for you:

> #### Unorthodox
>
> - Contrary to what is usual, traditional, or accepted; not orthodox.
>
> *"He frequently upset other scholars with his unorthodox views"*

([ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unorthodox))

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest [*atypical*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/atypical):

> **atypical** adjective
>
> different from all others of the same type:
>
> - The sociable behaviour of lions is considered atypical of the cat family.

Cambridge Dictionary

Answer (score 3):

Consider **maverick**

> From [Thesaurus.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/maverick):
>
> 1. a lone dissenter, as an intellectual, an artist, or a politician, who takes an independent stand apart from his or her associates.
>      *Synonyms: nonconformist, individualist; free thinker; loner, lone wolf*.
> 2. a person pursuing rebellious, even potentially disruptive, policies or ideas. *Synonyms: rebel, cowboy; loose cannon*.

Comment: This also seems to imply more intention than the OP has requested.

Answer (score 3):

Not an adjective, but you may like ***outlier*** - someone/something behaving differently compared to the "mainstream".

ODO:

> **[outlier](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/outlier)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** A person or thing situated away or detached from the main body or system:
>
> ‘a western outlier in the Andaman archipelago’
>
> **1.1** A person or thing differing from all other members of a particular group or set:
>
> ‘then there are the corporate outliers, people who just don't fit into
>   the culture of the company’

Answer (score 2):

To keep with the **stream** metaphor:

> going against the flow

Answer (score 2):

[***unusual***](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/unusual)

> not usual, common, or ordinary; uncommon in amount or degree; exceptional:
>   an unusual sound; an unusual hobby; an unusual response.

*(dictionary.com)*

You can also say *unconventional*.

Your example:

> I'm a bit **unusual**, compared with other students on campus, in that my week schedule is quite packed with events *except* for Friday evenings.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with ***original***, defined by [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/original) as:

> Not dependent on other people's ideas; inventive or novel.

This might however have a little more underlying meaning that requested, but I find that it would suit the given example pretty well:

> My week schedule is quite packed with events except Friday evening, **which is rather original**.

Answer (score -1):

> **Underground:** Art, opinion or organization that exists outside of mainstream society or culture.

Source: [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Underground&defid=2719879) (June 9, 2002).

Comment: Please [edit] to add [citations to reliable sources](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) that support the assertions made here. Unsourced material may be disputed or [deleted](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: This submission consists largely of a slightly altered (but entirely uncredited) version of the definition of _underground_ [posted on Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Underground&defid=2719879) on June 9, 2002, by Gyro (it's definition 2 on that page). English Language & Usage is quite strict about citing (and when possible linking to) sources of wording used in answers. Please identify your sources properly.

Comment: ... _Underground_ is a valid suggestion, by the way, so I've edited the wording of the definition in your answer slightly to match the original Urban Dictionary wording, and I've added the appropriate citation and formatting.